# PhotoSwipe is not working on first time page load

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, mobile, photoswipe

I am using Photoswipe gallery with jQuery Mobile. The first selection, when clicked shows just the image with full URL and does not work the gallery way. When I go back and select again, it works fine.The ps is working after a first failure/refresh of page.

Please check the link below.it's my mobile website.
http://w3qatar.info/aldarmobi

When we check the link Properties> any property from the list > View more photos ... under this you can find the thumbnails. When we click the thumbnail first it will load the original image without gallery view.But when we go back and try again ,it will work.i'm using opera mobile emulator for testing. Drupal 7 with Mobile_jquery theme. Jquery mobile is used in this site.

**inside code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://w3qatar.info/aldarmobi/sites/all/themes/mobile_jquery/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w3qatar.info/aldarmobi/sites/all/themes/mobile_jquery/lib/klass.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w3qatar.info/aldarmobi/sites/all/themes/mobile_jquery/scripts/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function(window, PhotoSwipe){

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

        var
                options = {},
                instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( window.document.querySelectorAll('#gallery li a'), options );

        }, false);

        }(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

    </script>
```

**html part:**

```
<ul id="gallery" class="gallery">
<li><a href="imageurl1" rel="external"><img src="imageurl1" alt="image name1" /></a></li>
<li><a href="imageurl2" rel="external"><img src="imageurl2" alt="image name2" /></a></li>
<li><a href="imageurl3" rel="external"><img src="imageurl3" alt="image name3" /></a></li>
<li><a href="imageurl4" rel="external"><img src="imageurl4" alt="image name4" /></a></li>
</ul
```

Could you please help me?
I want to work this in iPhone devices and android phones.

thanks in advance.

harikris.

Comment: Sometimes i found new error "uncaught exception:Code.PhotoSwipe.createInstance: No images to passed".

Answer (score 0):

I show your code you are using jQuery so why not do everything with it.

Can you change your code like below and see it works or not

```
(function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('div.p-img_more')
            .live('pageshow', function(e){

                var 
                    currentPage = $(e.target),
                    options = {},
                    photoSwipeInstance = $("ul.gallery a", e.target).photoSwipe(options,  currentPage.attr('id'));

                return true;

            })

            .live('pagehide', function(e){

                var 
                    currentPage = $(e.target),
                    photoSwipeInstance = PhotoSwipe.getInstance(currentPage.attr('id'));

                if (typeof photoSwipeInstance != "undefined" &amp;&amp; photoSwipeInstance != null) {
                    PhotoSwipe.detatch(photoSwipeInstance);
                }

                return true;

            });

    });

}(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
```

Comment: hello,
I added the above code ,but it is not working at first load or the next page refresh . could you please check it...